# Change Something about an App In-Game

Tags: ios

I'm working on a baseball card game for iOS.  I have completed much of the code, but am now trying to make the method where I will allow the user to select a new pitcher.  I have created a View Controller that will display when the user presses the "Change Pitcher" button, but I'm not sure how I should implement this View Controller, because I want the game to basically pause while the user selects a new pitcher, and then resume with the new pitcher that the user selected.  I initially was going to use a PopOver controller, but now I'm not sure that that's what I'm really looking for.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could use to select a new pitcher and then go back to the game such that the game will not have changed when I get back to it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement to methods in your game controller: `pause` and `resume`

in these methods you basically should do: `self.isPaused = YES;` or `self.isPaused = NO;` of course define this property

in you main game loop check whether game is paused or not before going to next iteration

call these methods before PopOver displaying and after pitcher selection

Comment: I am inside a View Controller called "BasicViewController".  When I try to use self.isPaused = YES, I am getting a code error that says "Property "isPaused" is not found on object of type "BasicViewController *".  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JosiahNusbaum yes, you missed my words _of course define this property_